# Python Panda DF - how to check if specific character exist in whole DF and globally replace it

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I want to check if there is character '|' in a whole Panda DF.

After that step - want to globrally replace all '|' with some other character.

I know to check if specific cell contains character:

```
df['a'].str.contains('|')
```

But how to check that globally and also replace globally?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can using

```
df = df.apply(lambda x : x.str.replace('-','something'))
```

Or

```
df = df.replace({'-':'something'},regex=True)
```

Comment: How to detect if there is any "|" character (and count) how many characters are there in DF before replacing?

Comment: @Joe using str.contains with apply

Answer (score 0):

```
np.sum([df[col].str.contains(r"\|", na=False) for col in df]) # gives sum
df.replace("|","") #replace the string
```